# Polymer message box with default button

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

Using Polymer 2 and `paper-dialog` I have created message boxes for my application. For the usual information boxes with only an OK button I would like the enter key to trigger the same handler as the button does. Any idea how to accomplish this?

Note that I also implemented an InputBox and there I used the `on-keydown` event of the single input element. But for an information box there is no text input element - only static text and an OK button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `keydown`-handler on the `paper-dialog` itself, and have that handler trigger the button's `click`-handler:

```
<paper-dialog on-keydown="_onDialogKeyDown">
  <button id="myButton" on-click="_submit">OK</button>
</paper-dialog>

// in Polymer element
_onDialogKeyDown(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    this.$.myButton.click();
  }
}
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/zpbgxV?editors=1010)

Comment: @NicolasR No problem :)